# How create a Benchmark in Scala

Tags: performance, scala, memory-management, benchmarking

I want to do a benchmark between a compiler that I developed and Apache Jena, the think is that I have different queries to run but I need to know the memory usage in the different one, and the time execution. 
For the time I am doing the following:

```
    val t1 = System.nanoTime  //time one starts here
    val i: interpreterVRC = new interpreterVRC(q, d)
    val x =(System.nanoTime - t1) / 1e9d //time one finish here

    //////***************CONFIGURACION DE JENA

    val in: InputStream = FileManager.get.open("peel.rdf")
    //val in: InputStream = FileManager.get.open("dbpedia-johnpeel-agents.rdf")
    val Jena = new JenaRdf(in)
    /** *************** Queries Execution Jena **************/
    val t2 = System.nanoTime  // time two starts here
    Jena.query_exec(q)
    println((System.nanoTime - t1) / 1e9d,x) //prints time two and time 1
```

However, I need to perform this operation like 10 times and get the time average of this times executions. Then my question is if there is a way to implement this benchmarks, and How Can I know the memory usage in each execution?

Comment: check out http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/

Comment: Hello, I am working with SBT and Scala, JMH does not support Scala and SBT

Comment: [Scalameter](https://scalameter.github.io/) is supposed to be quite good. (I haven't' tried it.) [Thyme](https://github.com/Ichoran/thyme) is rather old but I've found it easy to install and employ.